# increment variable inside a wrapper

Tags: bash

unfortunately I am very new to shell programming. What I want to do is following:
The output (printf) should be written to a logfile.

I wrote a wrapper (which seems to work):

```
exec "${@:2}" >>stupid.log
```

Another aim is to limit the size of my logfile. So I would like to increment a variable everytime a line was written. At counter max I want to begin at the start of the logfile.

How can I realize that?

Comment: I just answered another question by you with respect to a wrapper. Are the question related?  Should answers to both questions result in 1 wrapper?? Please give an example of the output of your program and of the line as it should be written to the log.

Comment: In a script you cannot begin at the start of a logfile in the way of over-writing the existing contents. You can only append a file or create an empty file.

Comment: Hey Willem. Yes, I wanted to keep the questions simple. My program outputs one line of text per second. This is only for test purposes at the moment. I want to add the uptime and append each line to a log file. This file must be size-limited.

Comment: @WillemK Instead of overwriting I want to change the logfile to logfile2.log and later again back to logfile1.log

Comment: That is a tricky one. You would have to register somewhere which logfile is in use by the wrapper. I mean, when the wrapper starts, it does not know anything about the last time it ran unless  you give it a config file to process before starting its actual work. That is not your basic shell scripting, that is advance scripting. Not something I can teach you in a few minutes.

Comment: You say you want to keep the questions simply. Unfortunately, you look that way in your mind but you must realize that combining the answer people give you, may be harder to compile to 1 wrapper than you think. It might be better to list all the requirements that you have for the wrapper, hoping some scripting enthusiast is willing to help you during the development process.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem with help of you and the answers of the other topic 979128.
It is forwarding the program's output to |{while read; do ...}
Inside the curly brackets I increment a variable to count lines and log_file_counter. 
For me the main problem was to build a loop and use the output of my program within the loop -> didn't know about "read" and how to use it in a loop.